# MySQL - find difference between rows of the same table

Tags: mysql, query-help

I have a table containing aggregated results with timestamps - meaning each result per time is the total so far:

```
date       | time  | ip       | result
---------------------------------------
2011-03-01 | 10:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 200
2011-03-01 | 11:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 303
2011-03-01 | 12:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 415
2011-03-01 | 13:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 628
2011-03-01 | 10:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 198
2011-03-01 | 11:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 234
2011-03-01 | 12:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 373
2011-03-01 | 13:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 512
```

I'm trying to formulate a query that'll get the deltas between each time range:

```
date       | time  | ip       | diff
---------------------------------------
2011-03-01 | 10:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 200
2011-03-01 | 11:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 103
2011-03-01 | 12:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 112
2011-03-01 | 13:00 | 10.0.0.1 | 213
2011-03-01 | 10:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 198
2011-03-01 | 11:00 | 10.0.0.2 |  36
2011-03-01 | 12:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 139
2011-03-01 | 13:00 | 10.0.0.2 | 139
...
```

So each row per date / ip grouping subtracts the one before it (or 0). 
Any simple way to do this? thanks.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on how the date change is handled. Does the result start from zero on every day, or starts from zero only on the begginning of the file?

Comment: What if there is a 11:00 data point and there's no 10:00, only 09:00 or none before that day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution without variables. I assume you have your initail data in a table called `thetable`.

```
SELECT date, time, ip,
    result - IFNULL( (
        SELECT MAX( result ) 
        FROM thetable
        WHERE ip = t1.ip
        AND ( date < t1.date
            OR date = t1.date AND time < t1.time )
    ) , 0) AS diff
FROM thetable AS t1
ORDER BY ip, date, time
```

Here we get the previous value with a subselect (the maximal `result` of the preceding timestamps from the same `ip`). `IFNULL` gives us a 0 if this was the first value, so initial results are displayed correctly.

I also recommend adding the following index to `thetable`:

```
CREATE INDEX sort1 ON thetable (ip, date, time);
```

Comment: Good solution, more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. It had a little problem with the handling of `date` field. Now it's OK.

Comment: I had some troubles too, with variables ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SET @f_rank = 0;
SET @s_rank = 0;
SET @f_date = NULL;
SET @f_ip = NULL;
SET @s_date = NULL;
SET @s_ip = NULL;
SELECT t1.date, t1.time, t1.ip, IF(t2.result IS NULL, t1.result, t1.result - t2.result) diff FROM
    (SELECT *, IF(@f_date = date AND @f_ip = ip, @f_rank:=@f_rank + 1, @f_rank:=1) AS rank, @f_date := date, @f_ip := ip FROM table1 ORDER BY date, ip, time) t1
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, IF(@s_date = date AND @s_ip = ip, @s_rank:=@s_rank + 1, @s_rank:=1) AS rank, @s_date := date, @s_ip := ip FROM table1 ORDER BY date, ip, time) t2
  ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.ip = t2.ip AND (t1.rank = t2.rank + 1);

+------------+----------+----------+------+
| date       | time     | ip       | diff |
+------------+----------+----------+------+
| 2011-03-01 | 10:00:00 | 10.0.0.1 |  200 |
| 2011-03-01 | 11:00:00 | 10.0.0.1 |  103 |
| 2011-03-01 | 12:00:00 | 10.0.0.1 |  112 |
| 2011-03-01 | 13:00:00 | 10.0.0.1 |  213 |
| 2011-03-01 | 10:00:00 | 10.0.0.2 |  198 |
| 2011-03-01 | 11:00:00 | 10.0.0.2 |   36 |
| 2011-03-01 | 12:00:00 | 10.0.0.2 |  139 |
| 2011-03-01 | 13:00:00 | 10.0.0.2 |  139 |
+------------+----------+----------+------+
```